# Как накладываются приложения стандарта по CSS "Appendix D. Default style sheet for HTML 4"и "Appendix F. Full property table"?

Tags: css, css3

Привет.

Вопрос по CSS. В приложении D стандарта CSS указаны стили по умолчанию - https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html#q22.0.
То есть, браузер как бы сам руками пишет файл стилей (в который записывает содержимое https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html#q22.0) и подключает его к документу.

С другой стороны, есть еще приложение F в стандарте CSS (полная таблица свойств) - https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html#q24.0.
Там в таблице есть столбец "Initial value" (начальное значение), которое, по-идее, присваивается свойству, если это свойство не задавать.

Рассмотрим вариант, что авторские стили вообще НЕ задаются, то есть я не подключаю файл стилей, не пишу элемент  и нет инлайновых стилей. Не понимаю, **как элемент набирает свои дефолтные свойства, пользуясь этими двумя приложениями D и F**. Они как-то накладываются друг на друга? **Насколько я понимаю, для любого элемента заданы вообще ВСЕ свойства, которые могут быть ему заданы, даже если я ничего вообще не задал - дефолтные свойства**.

Вопрос в том, что я до конца не понимаю, как получается тот набор свойств CSS, который я вижу в девтулс  браузера. например, я кликаю на элементе параграф во вкладке "elements", ниже открываются свойства

Во вкладке styles нарисована блочная модель данного элемента, а ниже указываются свойства. ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО свойств. некоторые из свойств имеют треугольник слева - можно открыть и посмотреть, где свойство задано, а остальные свойства посмотреть неяркого цвета, которые программист задал руками.

То есть, получается, что первоначально браузер берет элемент и присваивает ему все ВОЗМОЖНЫЕ свойства из таблицы-приложения F (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html#q24.0), потом браузер САМ КАК БЫ ПИШЕТ руками стили из приложения D стандарта CSS  стили по умолчанию  (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html#q22.0) и подключает их к документу, а только потом уже на этот пирог накладываются авторские стили программиста, которые написаны в документе или подключаются извне.

Правильно я понимаю или нет?

Comment: [_Appendix D. **This appendix is informative, not normative.**_](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html), аналогично и для `F`

Comment: приложение информативно, но не нормативно - что это значит?

Comment: Это значит, что предоставлено для информации, как пример, но не значит, что все браузеры будут ему следовать, то есть конкретные стили по умолчанию будут зависеть от конкретной реализации конкретного браузера